# Are there common etymological links to the words "judge", "Jew", "Jude" and 'justice"?

Tags: etymology

Are there common etymological links to the words "judge", "Jew", "Jude" and "justice"?  One source cited "yew" and/or "yewes" as possible Proto-Indo-European links to "Jew".  How about "jewel" amd "jewelry"?  Latin "iustitia" helps with "justice", but because of the shared Roman/Jewish history(Latin and Hebrew/Aramaic), I'm looking for good scholarship on the possible links between and among all these words.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you please cite the source you mention that connects "yewes" and "Jew"? You should also edit this post to add citations to a dictionary that gives etymological information such as http://www.etymonline.com.

Comment: The relevant pages from the Online Etymology Dictionary are [judge](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=judge&allowed_in_frame=0), [Jew](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Jew&allowed_in_frame=0), [Jude](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Jude&allowed_in_frame=0), [Judah](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Judah&allowed_in_frame=0), [justice](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=justice&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on "shared Roman/Jewish history"? It's not clear to me that they have one.

Comment: @sumelic stick those links in as an answer! I think that looks pretty conclusive that Jew and Jude are related, and Judge and Justice, but not related pairs.

Comment: Here is a link on the history of Roman domination of the people in Jerusalem.  http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/History/Romans.html

Comment: There are lots of links, but here is one from PBS, a trusted source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Judge** and **justice** come from the Proto-Indo-European root ***yewos** (law, precept, to bind) through Latin.  **Jew** comes from Hebrew through Aramaic to Greek to Latin to French.  There does not seem to be any connection between the Hebrew root and the PIE root. **Judah** and **Jude** come from the same Hebrew root as **Jew**. **Jewel** comes from **Latin** through French, with no relation between the Latin for jewel and the Latin for justice or the Latinized word for Jew.   See below for details, references and links.

The shared history of Romans and Jews does not go back much before Herod the Great in the first century BCE.  The Jews are a much older people than the Romans, and Hebrew is not related to the Indo-European family of languages.

From the *Families of Words*, Mario Pei (Harper and Brothers, 1962):

> The IE root ***yewos** "law, precept, to bind" is utilized by Latin to
>   manufacture the jus-, jur-root from which English ultimately derives
>   on the one hand just and all its compounds (**justice**, unjust, injustice,
>   justify, adjust, adjustment, etc);  on the other, its various jur-,
>   jure-, jury forms (juror, jury, jurist, jurisprudence,  jurisdiction, 
>   abjure, adjure, conjure, perjury, injure, injury, etc) .  In addition
>   the jus-root combines another widespread root, that of Latin dico "to
>   say" , to produce **judge**, judicial, prejudice  etc. There are also the
>   proper names such as Justin, Justine, Justinian and foreign
>   expressions accepted into the English vocabulary, such as jus gentium
>   and juste milieu."  (emphasis added)

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=j&p=4&allowed_in_frame=0), **Jew**

> **Jew (n.)**  Giw, Jeu, "a Jew
>   (ancient or modern), one of the Jewish race or religion," from
>   Anglo-French iuw, Old French giu (Modern French Juif), from Latin
>   **Iudaeum** (nominative Iudaeus), from Greek Ioudaios, from Aramaic
>   jehudhai (Hebrew y'hudi) "a Jew," from **Y'hudah** "Judah," literally
>   "celebrated," name of Jacob's fourth son and of the tribe descended
>   from him. (emphasis added)

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=j&p=8&allowed_in_frame=0), **Judah** and **Jude**

**Judah** proper name, biblical son of Jacob by Leah, also the name of a tribe of Israel, from Hebrew Yehudah, from stem of y-d-h, literally "praised

**Jude**  proper name, Hellenized form of Judah....

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=j&p=4&allowed_in_frame=0), **jewel**

**jewel** "article of value used for adornment," from Anglo-French juel, Old French jouel "ornament; present; gem, jewel" (12c.), which is perhaps [Watkins] from Medieval Latin jocale, from Latin jocus "pastime, sport," in Vulgar Latin "that which causes joy" (see joke (n.)). Another theory traces it to Latin gaudium, also with a notion of "rejoice" (see joy).